# Extract Consumer variable fields while mocking Lambda expression

Tags: java, lambda, junit, mockito

I have a method for batch updating a table.

Problem is when i try to call below block of code it is giving class cast
exception,

```
        when(session.doWork(any())).thenAnswer(invocation -> {
        Consumer<Connection> consumer = invocation.getArgument(0);
        consumer.accept(mockConnection);
        return null;
    });
```

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.paypal.compliance.data.process.eftns.dao.impl.EFTReportsDAO$$Lambda$9/170106909 cannot be cast to java.util.function.Consumer
```

on debugging in intellij i found that `invocation` has 2 arguments `arg$1` and `arg$2` , `arg$1` is the SQL statement and `arg$2` is a list of EFTReportsDO , how to extract these individually ?

Below are the method and test case

```
@Transactional(value = "test", propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
        public void mergeAllEftReports(List<EFTReportsDO> instanceList) {
            String updateSql = "UPDATE EFT_XYZ " +
                    "SET " +
                    "COMMENTS=?, " +
                    "PP_BATCH_SOURCE=?, " +
                    "WHERE " +
                    "PP_BATCH_ID=? " +
                    "AND REPORT_ID=?";
    
            try {
                Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
                session.doWork(connection -> {
                    try (PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(updateSql)) {
                        for (EFTReportsDO entity : instanceList) {
                            preparedStatement.setString(1, entity.getComments());
                            preparedStatement.setString(2, entity.getPpBatchSource());
                    
                            preparedStatement.setString(3, entity.getId().getPpBatchId());
                            preparedStatement.setString(4, entity.getId().getReportId());
                            preparedStatement.addBatch();
                        }
                        preparedStatement.executeBatch();
                    }
                });
            } finally {
                entityManager.flush();
                entityManager.close();
            }
        }
```

```
     @Test
            public void testMergeAllEftReports() throws SQLException {
               // Arrange
                List<EFTReportsDO> instanceList = new ArrayList<>();
                EFTReportsDO eftReportsDO = new EFTReportsDO(); // create an instance of EFTReportsDO
                instanceList.add(eftReportsDO);
                when(entityManager.unwrap(Session.class)).thenReturn(session);
                Connection connection = mock(Connection.class);
                PreparedStatement preparedStatement = mock(PreparedStatement.class);
                when(connection.prepareStatement(anyString())).thenReturn(preparedStatement);
        
                // Act & Assert
                 when(session.doWork(any())).thenAnswer(invocation -> {
                Consumer<Connection> consumer = invocation.getArgument(0);
                consumer.accept(mockConnection);
                return null;
            });
                // Call the method under test
                eftReportsDAO.mergeAllEftReports(instanceList);
        
                verify(preparedStatement, times(1)).executeBatch();
        
                // Verify that flush and close methods are called on the entityManager
                verify(entityManager, times(1)).flush();
                verify(entityManager, times(1)).close();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your lambda cannot be cast to `Consumer<Connection>`, it must match the type of SAM type expected by `Session.doWork`, namely `Work`

```java
doAnswer((invocation) -> {
    Work jdbcWork = invocation.getArgument(0);
    jdbcWork.execute(connection);
    return null;
}).when(session).doWork(any());
```

Note: `session.doWork` returns void, so I used doAnswer - when, instead of when - thenAnswer

In general, you cannot cast between 2 different SAM interfaces, even if their structure is identical:

```java
interface StringConsumer1 {
    void execute(String s1);
}

interface StringConsumer2 {
    void execute(String s1);
}

@Test
void testLambdaConversionFails() {
    Throwable thrown = catchThrowable(() -> {
        StringConsumer1 l1 = (aaa) -> System.out.println(aaa);
        StringConsumer2 l2 = (StringConsumer2) l1;
    });

    assertThat(thrown).isInstanceOf(ClassCastException.class);

}
```

In your case `Consumer<Connection>` is not identical to `Work` (method name and checked exceptions differ)

Comment: Thanks for clarifying . This worked successfully

Answer (score 1):

The code is a bit tricky to test since there is an anonymous implementation of `Work` which is calling when doing `session.doWork`. The argument of that method is also a mocked `connection` class and everything is dependent on that mock `connection` class.

Hence in your test, you need to capture the lambda expression and test the functionality in it. I have written the minimal amount of code to demonstrate this.

The class to be tested;

```
public class MainClass {

    @Autowired
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public void executeQuery() {
        Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);

        try {
            session.doWork(connection -> {
                System.out.println("calling the lambda implementation");
                PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("update some_table set name = ? where id = ? ");
                preparedStatement.setString(1, "new_name");
                preparedStatement.setLong(2, 1L);
                preparedStatement.execute();
            });
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Error occurred");
        } finally {
            entityManager.flush();
            entityManager.close();
        }
    }
}
```

The test;

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class TestHibernateWork {

    @Mock
    EntityManager entityManager;

    @InjectMocks
    MainClass underTest;

    @Test
    void process() {
        Session session = mock(Session.class);
        when(entityManager.unwrap(any())).thenReturn(session);

        // this will help capture the real anonymous implementation of Work; which is the lambda expression
        ArgumentCaptor<Work> workArgumentCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Work.class);
        
        // Capture the lambda when doWork is called
        doNothing().when(session).doWork(workArgumentCaptor.capture());

        // call the method to test the lambda
        underTest.executeQuery();

        // get the captured implementation of Work, which is the lambda expression.
        Work work = workArgumentCaptor.getValue();

        try {
            Connection connection = mock(Connection.class);
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = mock(PreparedStatement.class);
            when(connection.prepareStatement(any())).thenReturn(preparedStatement);

            // call the real implementation of work captured previously using the mock connection
            work.execute(connection);

            // verify the calls made on prepareStatement
            verify(preparedStatement).setString(1, "new_name");
            verify(preparedStatement).setLong(2, 1L);
            verify(preparedStatement).execute();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for clarifying trying this approach